# SO GreaseMonkey Support - Here or SuperUser

Tags: discussion, greasemonkey

I'm having trouble getting one of the GreaseMonkey scripts that Shog9 wrote to work ([The DailyRepLimit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32087/how-close-are-you-to-an-epic-legendary-badge/32164#32164) tracker).  Should I post the question on how to fix it here or on superuser?  GreaseMonkey in general is working, because the question dashboard is working.

The issue: 
  Question marks instead of symbols.  This is in Firefox 3.5.5.

[image: Image FAIL]

Screenshot is from my page, works the same way on everyone's page.

Comment: Hey, shog9 has his own tag! Just beat him till he answers, Ross.

Comment: Aha! Let me guess: you copy/pasted the script into a text editor instead of clicking on the link to the one I host. And didn't have your text editor configured for UTF-8 (or any other proper Unicode encoding)...

Comment: I've updated the script listing to use an entity (&#9679;) instead of the literal character - update your local script and see if that doesn't take care of the problem...

Answer (score 2):

Find the link.  If he posted it here, add a response to his question or answer.  If it's on [userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/), there's facilities there for discussion and reporting issues.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could always email me I suppose...

Failing that, describe in a comment exactly *how* it's not working. Or, since you have this question sitting here anyway, do it here and include screenshots of a Reputation page with hand-drawn circles outlining the bit where the rep cap summary was supposed to show up but isn't.

Comment: @Shog9: Is the script accurate for your account?  I installed it using the link you provided and it's telling me I don't even have the Epic badge yet, which I do.

Comment: @Bill: not sure it's accurate for *anyone's* account... It's just using the raw data (rep by day) from the rep graph, and there's a really good chance that doesn't jive with what's used for actual badge calculations (for instance, if you hit the cap and then down-voted something, the graph would show only a 199 increase and the script wouldn't count it). Note the comments on the original thread - plenty of folks initially awarded the badges who the script listed at well under the threshold.